How were angles measured in ancient times?
What is one degree (angle measurement)? I know that we calculate one second using atomic clock, one kilogram using Planck's constant, one meter using speed of light but how do we define one degree? If someone know how degrees were calculated in ancient times, please tell.

That is not calculated. It is not measured. It is an arbitrary definition. They just liked the number 360.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Suppose we don't have any angle measuring tool and we are given a triangle with measurements of its side then how can we calculate the interior anglesof th triangle or in general any geometrical shape?

Have you learned trigonometry?

This is better asked in the history of science site: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

I mean how scientist decide what is one degree.

I am nearly sure that our current degree system is used since the Babylonians. Anyways, degree does not really need an SI definition, simply because it is a dimensionless quantity. The most obvious unit for that is the full circle, the perpendicular or the radian. But I think, the ancient people all used our degrees. HSM will say you, I believe, what you want.

Your question asks about ancient methods of measuring (or constructing) angles, but in some comments you ask about modern methods. So what is your real question? There are simple techniques for constructing or measuring angles without a protractor, assuming you have a ruler (and can construct a right angle).

One degree is defined as $\frac 1 {360}$ of a full revolution. If you are creating a measuring instrument it is probably more convenient to define it as $\frac 1 {90}$ of a right angle or $\frac 1 {60}$ of the angle of an equilateral triangle, since there are simple geometric methods of creating a right angle or an equilateral triangle.
So you draw a circle, measure off a chord that is equal in length to the circle's radius - this gives you an angle of $60$ degrees - then take a piece of string and measure the length of this $60$ degree angle around the circumference of the circle. Divide this length by $60$ and you can mark off an angle of $1$ degree on the circle.

Does our modern instruments used to measure angles are based on this principal or not?

the 360-degree circle has its origins in Babylonian astronomy combined with the need for a consistent bureaucratic calendar in the Babylonian state. As a bonus, it has factors of 2, 3, and 5, yielding convenient integer answers for subdivisions of the circle.

This doesn't answer my question.

Then I do not know what it is you want.
